# Find $x$ such that $ 2^{16^x} = 16^{2^x} $.

Tags: exponentiation

Find $x$ such that $ 2^{16^x} = 16^{2^x}.$

I am a bit confused, what will happen when we expand $16^{2^x}$, will we get  $4^{2^{2^x}}$ or $4^{2^{x+1}}$ ?

Comment: $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$ and $ a^{bc}={(a^b)^c}$.${(4^2)^{2^x}}={4^{2\times 2^x}}$

Comment: $16^{2^x} = 16^{(2^x)} = (4^2)^{(2^x)} = 4^{2\cdot2^x} = 4^{(2^{x+1})}$

Comment: What they said. $a^{b^c}$ *always* means $a^{(b^c)}$ not $(a^b)^c$ because if you meant the latter, you'd simply write $a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that $2^{16^x} = 16^{2^x}$ is $2^{2^{4x}} = 2^{2^{x+2}}$

then $4x = x + 2$ and get $x = 2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach

$$16^{2^x} = [2^4]^{2^x} = 2^{4 \times 2^x}.$$

Since this is equal to $2^{16^x}$ you have

$$16^x = 4 \times 2^x \implies 8^x = 4 \implies x = (2/3).$$

Answer (score 1):

Take log on base 2, then $$16^x \log_2 2=2^x \log_2 16. \implies 16^x= 4. 2^x$ \implies 2^{4x}=2^{x+2} \implies 4x=x+2 \implies x=2/3.$$